# Too many "and's"

Tags: commas, repetition

Is there a way to somehow change this sentence without making it longer?

"Our brain is a truly fascinating *and* complex organ *and* even though neuroscientists *and* cognitive scientists are only beginning to make breakthroughs, someday, I believe, they would revolutionize the lives of people."

Comment: For the record, there aren't too many _and_’s in that sentence to me. It reads perfectly natural the way it is, and there's no pressing need to break it up or othewise ‘fix’ it.

Comment: To many apostrophes: the plural or “and” is “and”s. You have used the possessive form. Just one possessive of “and” would be to much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break it up and omit needless words, e.g.,

> Our brain is a fascinating and complex organ. Even though
>   scientists are only beginning to make breakthroughs, someday, I
>   believe, they will revolutionize people's lives.

Comment: Yeah, I thought it would be the only option. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: I'd change that *would* to *will*.